# Getting RC255 when running Testscript, but not when i run the specific line in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, robotframework

I already tried finding similar questions here, but it seems that RC255 in combination with Robot Framework is quite rare, or my Google skills aren't as good as i thought.

I have a testscript that, amongst other things, creates a user in a GUI and then asks the database what the user's id is. To do so, the code creates a sql file with a query and then runs that file against the database. This results in the following(anonimyzed) line:

```
echo EXIT | ./sqlcl/bin/sql.exe -L -S "username/password@//dbconnectionstring" @C:\testware\robot-``framework-testsuite\tool\sql\0_run_select_from_table.sql
```

This line originates from the following line in the code:

```
${result}  Run Process  echo EXIT | ./sqlcl/bin/sql.exe -L -S "${CONNECTIONSTRING}" @${sql_file}  stderr=${RESULTS}${/}stderr.txt  shell=yes
```

When i run the script, this line returns nothing, but should return the result of a simple select query.
Looking into the report that Robot Framework generates it shows that it only took .2 seconds to run and returned the following:

```
${result} = <result object with rc 255>
```

However, when i run that specific line directly in the terminal, it does clearly take longer to run and returns the expected result.

**Question:**
So the line does work and the data does exist in the DB, but why am i still getting the error?

**Some other things i tried**
I have also tested the query in SQL Developer, that works, and tried using different folders and path structures, but that seems to get me even further away from the solution(at first i had some spaces in the path, so i used "path" but that gave even more trouble).

output STDERR file:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you show us how do you call this command. You should try to output stderr message, that should tell you more.

Comment: How do you mean call this command? I can already inform you that the Echo Exit line with the filled in variables is executed in the Visual Code Terminal and is based on the line i just added in the original question(below the line with the filled in variables). I also just added the STDERR output, didn't know that file existed.

Comment: the stderr says there is a unrecognized . so i quess it is time to find that specific . and see if i can find a way around it. Thanks already ;)